# How can I simulate multi-touch in the Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I’m running the Windows Phone 7 emulator/simulator and I need to simulate the two-finger pinch/zoom gesture.  Any tips?

Comment: Multi-touch hardware? Two mice!? Is there anything along the lines of “hold down a modifier key”? This is absurd, though I do appreciate the answers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a good guide here: http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7

Basically you will need to use the Multi-Touch Vista project on CodePlex available here: http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/ and 2 <del>mouses</del> mice.

Comment: Amazing. Too much work for me, it’s not super critical — but I would expect something a bit more reasonable from Microsoft!

Comment: I've used MultiTouch Vista with WP7 emulator.

Comment: very easy to setup. Then I've downloaded WP7 Gesture Recognizer and Behavior / Triggers (can download code from here http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-353323_WP7_Gesture_Recognizer_and_Behavior_Triggers.aspx) and everything worked just perfect

Answer (score 4):

You'll need Windows 7 and a multi-touch monitor; in that setup 2 touchpoints are supported natively by the emulator.

There's no easy software or emulation API support for this.

Answer (score 3):

Laurent Bugnion's [MultiTouch library](http://multitouch.codeplex.com/) (supports Silverlight 4 WPF, and WP7) enables simulated multitouch in the WP7 emulator.

Comment: This requires using two mice or genuine multi-touch hardware, right? That’s what the accepted answer’s guide indicates (and boy is that a long guide).

Comment: No, Laurent's Multitouch Beahavior enables _simulated_ multitouch through mouse clicks, i.e position the first touch point (which stays fixed), and then touch/drag again for the second (movable) touch point.