# Simulate pinch gesture in Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: emulation, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I simulate multi-touch in the Windows Phone 7 emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751552/how-can-i-simulate-multi-touch-in-the-windows-phone-7-emulator)

I'm trying to simulate a pinch gesture so I can zoom out in a map, but I can't seem to figure out how?! Seems to me like a rookie problem, but everywhere I've checked they tell me there's supposed to be a pinch button in the toolbar on the right in the emulator.

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this still a duplicate? The new Windows Phone 8.1 emulator now simulates *basic* multi-touch input out of the box; unfortunately, I'm not sure if the older Windows Phone 7 emulator will ever get that feature right out of the box. See Multi-point Input section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629629.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows Phone emulator only supports multitouch gestures with a multitouch device.  You would have to have a screen, or touchpad to work with it.  Also, there has been comments about using two mice and there is a project on codeplex http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com for it.

A short video demonstration about using MultiTouchVista to emulate a pinch gesture on Windows Phone can be found here: http://vimeo.com/10330829

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found what you are referring to here, but I thought maybe the WP8 SDK shipped with the possibility since the pinch is supported in the [W8 emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/30/microsoft-windows-simulator-touch-emulation.aspx). I thought maybe my emulator was bugged or something! Pretty strange that it is not included in the WP8 SDK.

Comment: Agree. Having to use some codeplex codes and tutorial is not normal. But if we only communicate with the emulator using TCP/IP, I guess it's possible to just code a cheap winform app to achieve it. You'd bind it to some hotkeys. And knowing the exact stuff to send to the emulator, that would be simpler than installing all these 3rd party stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A great option is to get one of those cheap android tablets and turn it into a second monitor. Then you can do touch gestures in the emulator. Also, the phones are so fast now that I often just debug on the phone and skip the emulator.