# windows phone 8 emulator, internet Explorer zoom shortcut, or how to pinch zoom

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8 emulator, I can zoom my webpage in Internet Explorer using double click on screen but I need to zoom my webpage slowly, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in this post: [Simulate pinch gesture in Windows Phone 8 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453410/simulate-pinch-gesture-in-windows-phone-8-emulator)

Basically, if you want to pinch-zoom, you need a multitouch device that allows you to do it!