# Multitouch on Emulator (Windows Phone 8.0)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, slider, windows-phone-8-emulator

In my Windows Phone 8.0 project, I am using 2 slider(right and left side) for controlling my robot but it is possible to use multitouching on Windows Phone Emulator? I would like to control 2 slider at the same time.

**Sliders**

[image]

Comment: Did you read this answer?: [Simulate pinch gesture in Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13456212/1970882). It seems what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it on a computer with multi-touch then the emulator will pass that through.

If not then you can only test single-touch or specific gestures such as rotate and pinch-zoom with the "Multi-touch Input" tool (the hand on the emulator's toolbar). It will be a bit limited, but you should be able to use this tool to run both sliders simultaneously, if not independently.

--Rob